# How to fetch value from one schema and update in other using middlewares in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

While updating Movie documents, get value from User collection and save it with the documents getting updated in Movie.

```
Movie.pre('update', function (next) {
   var id = this._update.$set.userid;
   var some = this;
   User.findOne({userid: id}, function(err, post) {
       // how should we add the firstname to current movie document and
       let update query update it all. Something like this...
       some.firstname = post.firstname;
       next();
   });
});

// update query
Movie.statics.saveMovieDetails = function(requestData, callback) {
this.update({userid:requestData.userid},
    { $set:{
            userid   : requestData.userid,
            name     : requestData.name,
            location : requestData.location,
            language : requestData.language,
            date     : requestData.date
        }
    },{upsert:true}, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it. Correct me if i am wrong or if there is any better way to solve this problem.

```
Movie.pre('update', function (next) {
  var id = this._update.$set.userid;
  var some = this;
  User.findOne({userid: id}, function(err, post) {
      some._update.$set.firstname = post.firstname;
      next();
  });
});
```